# На мобилках не работает autoplay

Tags: android, html5, iphone

вот мой код:

```
<video id="video" preload="auto" autoplay muted loop>
              <source src="video/Depositphotos_183300920_hd1080.mp4" type='video/mp4'></source>
              <source src="video/Depositphotos_183300920_hd1080.webm" type='video/webm'></source>
              <source src="video/Depositphotos_183300920_hd1080.ogv" type='video/ogv'></source>
</video>
```

На мобилках(андроид и айфон) не работает autoplay. Но на топовых сайтах, как этот https://versett.com/, все работает.

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была на IOS. Нужно вписать **playsinline** и на яблуке все заработает!